# OS X Get info via Terminal

Tags: python, osx-lion

is there a way to get the information of the application using a terminal command? or python

eg. application QuickTime Player then hit Ctrl + I

Comment: what information do you want to get? For permission, you can use `ls -al` command

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through Applescript, like:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to open information window of alias "Macintosh HD:Applications:QuickTime Player.app"'
```

There's a post [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-10149.html) that shows some really good examples.

However, if there's particular information from that window that you want (rather than the window itself), please revise your question, as there could be better ways to get at it.